# Slick Carousel Image padding not working

Tags: css, slick.js

Image padding inside slick carousel not working. Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wzf6kaxr/3/

```
<div class="testimonial-shortcode-wrapper carousel">
  <div class="slider-for">
    <div class="testimonial-item"> <i class="ion-quote" style="color:cc9900;"></i><br/> Holatest hola amiogos</div>
    <div class="testimonial-item"> <i class="ion-quote" style="color:cc9900;"></i><br/> Holatest hola amiogos</div>
    <div class="testimonial-item"> <i class="ion-quote" style="color:cc9900;"></i><br/> Holatest hola amiogos</div>
    <div class="testimonial-item"> <i class="ion-quote" style="color:cc9900;"></i><br/> Holatest hola amiogos</div>
    <div class="testimonial-item"> <i class="ion-quote" style="color:cc9900;"></i><br/> Holatest hola amiogos</div>
    <div class="testimonial-item"> <i class="ion-quote" style="color:cc9900;"></i><br/> Holatest hola amiogos</div>
    <div class="testimonial-item"> <i class="ion-quote" style="color:cc9900;"></i><br/> Holatest hola amiogos</div>
    <div class="testimonial-item"> <i class="ion-quote" style="color:cc9900;"></i><br/> Holatest hola amiogos</div>
  </div>

  <div class="testimonial-nav slider-nav">
    <div class="nav-item" style="width: 101px;">
      <img width="120" height="120" src="https://webmose.com/sjbdev/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Cristiano.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
      <h3 class="testimonial-title">Cristiano Grow</h3>
      <p class="testimonial-position">Partner / Director</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item" style="width: 101px;">
      <img width="120" height="120" src="https://webmose.com/sjbdev/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Cristiano.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
      <h3 class="testimonial-title">Cristiano Grow</h3>
      <p class="testimonial-position">Partner / Director</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item" style="width: 101px;">
      <img width="120" height="120" src="https://webmose.com/sjbdev/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Cristiano.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
      <h3 class="testimonial-title">Cristiano Grow</h3>
      <p class="testimonial-position">Partner / Director</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item" style="width: 101px;">
      <img width="120" height="120" src="https://webmose.com/sjbdev/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Cristiano.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
      <h3 class="testimonial-title">Cristiano Grow</h3>
      <p class="testimonial-position">Partner / Director</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item" style="width: 101px;">
      <img width="120" height="120" src="https://webmose.com/sjbdev/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Cristiano.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
      <h3 class="testimonial-title">Cristiano Grow</h3>
      <p class="testimonial-position">Partner / Director</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item" style="width: 101px;">
      <img width="120" height="120" src="https://webmose.com/sjbdev/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Cristiano.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
      <h3 class="testimonial-title">Cristiano Grow</h3>
      <p class="testimonial-position">Partner / Director</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item" style="width: 101px;">
      <img width="120" height="120" src="https://webmose.com/sjbdev/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Cristiano.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
      <h3 class="testimonial-title">Cristiano Grow</h3>
      <p class="testimonial-position">Partner / Director</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS: not including here..almost 500 lines. please check fiddle.

js:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.testimonial-shortcode-wrapper').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    //var autoplay = $(this).attr('data-autoplay') == 'true' ? true : false;
    //var slide_duration = parseInt($(this).attr('data-slide-duration'));

    if ($this.hasClass('carousel')) {
      $this.find('.slider-for').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        fade: false,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 6000,
        asNavFor: $('.slider-nav', $this)
      });
      $this.find('.slider-nav').slick({
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        asNavFor: $('.slider-for', $this),
        dots: false,
        centerMode: true,
        variableWidth: true,
        variableHeight: true,
        centerPadding: '0px',
        focusOnSelect: true,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 991,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 3
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 767,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 3
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Image is overlapping each other without obeying the padding.
I couldn't find where is the problem that's why I'm asking your help.
[What I'm trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/809H7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to give padding to outer div with respect to the image instead giving padding to the image itself.

```
  .slick-slide{ padding:100px;}
```

Comment: In your fiddle the CSS is your custom. The outer div of the image is in SLICK.CSS .You didn't specified that class on your fiddle css i think .

Comment: slick.css contains the stock css provided with slick carousel. nothing custom there. Btw my problem solved automatically on my project code without doing anything :/

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

for all the image

Comment: @Sabbir , it will be better if you use appropriate image-size for that slider, or you can use 
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working demo. I have added margin to slick-slide class.

```
.slick-slide {
  margin:0 80px;
}
```

[`https://jsfiddle.net/wzf6kaxr/14/`](https://jsfiddle.net/wzf6kaxr/14/)